# Having trouble searching through graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, depth-first-search

Trying to do the [Count Luck](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-luck/copy-from/28359050) problem on Hackerrank. The task is to find a path through a forest of nodes to a target `*`, and given a guess `k` of the number of nodes on the target path that have more than 1 valid adjacent paths I have to determine if that guess is correct. If it is correct print "Impressed", otherwise "Oops!".

The player starts out at `'M'` and there is only 1 complete path to the target.  The player cannot walk through the `X` nodes. Valid paths consist of `.` nodes, you can only walk through there. Also, the player can only move up, down, left, or right.

Here's an example of the forest where 4 and 11 are the dimensions and 3 is the guess:

```
4 11
.X.X......X
.X*.X.XXX.X
.XX.X.XM...
......XXXX.
3
```

This prints "Impressed" because there are three nodes on the target path that have more than 1 valid adjacent path. That is, at (2, 9), (0, 5), and (3, 3). The guess was correct.

My approach was to do a depth first search and for each node, analyse each of its adjacent nodes and determine if they are valid. If there is more than 1 valid node (the node leading to the target + node(s) that lead to dead ends) then we decrement `k`. If by the time we find the target `k` is zero then we print "Impressed", otherwise "Oops!".

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct node {
  int x, y;

  node() = default;
  node(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y)
  {}
};

string makeGuess(vector<string> const& forest, int n, int m, node player, int k) {
  vector<vector<bool>> visited(n, vector<bool>(m));

  auto isUnvisitedNode = [&](node v)
    {return (0 <= v.x && v.x < n) && (0 <= v.y && v.y < m) && !visited[v.x][v.y];};

  std::stack<node> s;
  s.push(player);

  while (!s.empty()) {
    node elem = s.top();
    s.pop();

    if (!isUnvisitedNode(elem)) continue;
    int x = elem.x;
    int y = elem.y;
    visited[x][y] = true;

    if (forest[x][y] == 'X') continue;
    if (forest[x][y] == '*') break;

    std::queue<node> q;
    q.push(node(x, y-1));
    q.push(node(x, y+1));
    q.push(node(x-1, y));
    q.push(node(x+1, y));

    int numberOfPaths = 0;
    while (!q.empty()) {
      node v = q.front();
      q.pop();
      if (isUnvisitedNode(v)) {
        if (forest[v.x][v.y] == '.' || forest[v.x][v.y] == '*') {
          numberOfPaths++;
        }
      }
      s.push(v);
    }
    if (numberOfPaths > 1) k--;
  }

  if (k == 0)
    return "Impressed";
  else
    return "Oops!";
}

int main() {
  int n, m, i, j, k, p, t;
  node player;

  cin >> t;
  for (p = 0; p < t; ++p) {
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<string> forest(n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      string str; cin >> str;
      if ((j = str.find('M')) != string::npos)
        player = node(i, j);
      forest[i] = move(str);
    }
    cin >> k;
    cout << makeGuess(forest, n, m, player, k) << '\n';
  }
}
```

This code works for the above test case but fails for a few others. For example, this one. It prints "Oops!" when it is supposed to print "Impressed". Turns out `k` is decremented to `-2` instead of `0`.

```c++
41 41
.X.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
...XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...................
.X..X.X.X.X.X.X.X..XXXX*X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.
.XXXX.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
.XX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
.XX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
.XX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
.XX.X.X.X.XX.X.XX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X
.X.X.X.X.X.XXX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
X........................................
X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
.X.XX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.XX
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XMX.
.X....................................X..
..X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.X...................................X...
.XX.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.XX.XXXX.
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.XX.
.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.X.
.........................................
294
```

The code seems correct. I'm sure there's a small thing I'm overlooking.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Sounds like you may have already been using the debugger to get the unexpected value of `k`. The next step would be to put a breakpoint on `k--` and look for the cases where `k` was decremented and shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding another member to the node class, `count`, which is the number of times Hermonie waves her wand from `M` to `*`. For all adjacent nodes, I check if they are valid paths. If there are more than one valid paths we increment the `count` member of all the adjacent nodes and continue on with the search. By the end the target node will contain the answer and we check `k == lastNode.count`.

```c++
std::array<node, 4> arr = {{
  node(x, y - 1, last.count),
  node(x, y + 1, last.count),
  node(x - 1, y, last.count),
  node(x + 1, y, last.count)
}};

int count = 0;
for (auto const& v : arr) {
  if (isUnvisitedNode(v)) {
    if (forest[v.x][v.y] == '.' || forest[v.x][v.y] == '*') {
      count++;
    }
    else {
      visited[v.x][v.y] = true;
    }
  }
}

for (auto& v : arr) {
  if (count >= 2) v.count++;
  if (isUnvisitedNode(v)) s.push(v);
}
```